# Integrating Improper Integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I was assigned this integral - a fairly simple problem: $$\int^3_0\frac{1}{\sqrt{3-x}}\ dx$$ Becaause $f(x)$ is continuous only on $(0,3]$ we must take a left sided limit in order to properly solve. Doing this gets us: $$\lim_{t\to 3^-}\int^t _0\frac{1}{\sqrt{3-x}}\ dx$$Which is: $$\lim_{t\to3^-}(-2\sqrt{3-x}) |^t_0$$This is: $$-2\sqrt3+\lim_{t\to3^-}(-2\sqrt{3-t})$$
The second part of the problem becomes zero, leaving me with $-2\sqrt3$ as my answer. This looks great to me, but the real answer is $2\sqrt3$.

Why doesn't the answer have a negative? What did I do wrong that gave me that last negative at the end?

Comment: The leading - sign in the antiderivative shouldn't be there.  Check by by differentiating.

Comment: A negative times a negative is a positive; double check the fourth equation you've written; there should be another negative sign multiplying the $-2\sqrt{3}$ term

Comment: You need to subtract the evaluation at the lower bound.  It looks like you have added.

Comment: I see the problem: zero is the lower bound which means it is subtracted from the upper bound. Therefore I needed to subtract the negative which makes it positive.

Comment: Its “as $t$ approaches $3$ from the negative” so you write it as $t\to3^-$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $t$ approaches $3$ from the left we have

\begin{align}\lim_{t\to 3^-}\int^t _0\frac{1}{\sqrt{3-x}}\ dx&=\lim_{t\to 3^-}\Big[-2\sqrt{3-x}\Big]_0^t\\&=
\lim_{t\to 3^-}\Big(-2\sqrt{3-t}+2\sqrt{3}\Big)\\&=
\lim_{t\to 3^-}\Big(-2\sqrt{3-t}\Big)+2\sqrt{3}\\&=
0+2\sqrt{3}\\&=
2\sqrt{3}
\end{align}

so you made the following errors

1. You should write the limit as $t$ approaches $3$ from the left as $\lim_{t\to 3^-}$ instead of $\lim_{t^-\to 3}$.
2. After carrying through the limits of integration you claimed that

$$\lim_{t\to 3^-}\Big[-2\sqrt{3-x}\Big]_0^t=-2\sqrt{3}+\lim_{t\to 3^-}\Big(-2\sqrt{3-t}\Big)$$
which is false. You need to carry through the minus sign to the lower integration limit to form
$$\lim_{t\to 3^-}\Big[-2\sqrt{3-x}\Big]_0^t=\lim_{t\to 3^-}\Big(-2\sqrt{3-t}\Big)+2\sqrt{3}$$

Comment: Corrected the limit to be $3^-$